# Nexus S in reboot loop

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, boot-loop

My Nexus S (completely original) is stuck in a reboot loop. I don't know why. It just reboots, shuts down, and does the same again and again. I tried removing the battery, loading 100%, removing SIM etc.
I no longer care about the phone, but more about the pics of my two sons. The pics are on the iNAND flash memory (inside). I tried to connect to the PC, but its asking for Android 1.0 driver. Even with SDK 2.3 the Nexus isn't getting recognized.
Is there a way I can connect onto my Nexus and save my pics?

Thx for any help I can get.

A desperate dad.

Comment: Did you check our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info), and follow the first-aid steps described there? Take a special look at the Safe-Mode part.

Comment: What version of android are you running? Do you have root? Are you running a custom ROM?

Comment: I'm running 4.2.2. No custom ROM. When I try power + volume- to get into Safe modus, I see Safe modus on the left corner but it restarts again after a few seconds. When I try power + volume+ I get into recovery mode. I only have a few options, reboot, recovery, shut down. When I use recovery I get a pic of an android robot lying down with a big red sign above it and nothing else happens. I'm afraid I will never see the photo's of my two little sons again :(